# Drawing markers on a quadratic curve

Tags: graphics, geometry, html5-canvas, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to place evenly-spaced markers/dots on a quadratic curve drawn with HTML Canvas API. Found a nice article explaining how the paths are calculated in the first place, at [determining coordinates on canvas curve](http://www.independent-software.com/determining-coordinates-on-a-html-canvas-bezier-curve.html).

There is a formula, at the end, to calculate the angle:

```
function getQuadraticAngle(t, sx, sy, cp1x, cp1y, ex, ey) {
  var dx = 2*(1-t)*(cp1x-sx) + 2*t*(ex-cp1x);
  var dy = 2*(1-t)*(cp1y-sy) + 2*t*(ey-cp1y);
  return Math.PI / 2 - Math.atan2(dx, dy);
}
```

The x/y pairs that we pass, are the current position, the control point and the end position of the curve - exactly what is needed to pass to the canvas context, and `t` is a value from 0 to 1. Unless I somehow misunderstood the referenced article.

I want to do something very similar - place my markers over the distance specified `s`, rather than use `t`. This means, unless I am mistaken, that I need to calculate the length of the "curved path" and from there, I could probably use the above formula.

I found a solution for the length in JavaScript at  [length of quadratic curve](https://riptutorial.com/html5-canvas/example/18923/length-of-a-quadratic-curve). The formula is similar to:
[image: length of the curve formula].

And added the below function:

```
function quadraticBezierLength(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {
  let a, b, c, d, e, u, a1, e1, c1, d1, u1, v1x, v1y;

  v1x = x2 * 2;
  v1y = y2 * 2;
  d = x1 - v1x + x3;
  d1 = y1 - v1y + y3;
  e = v1x - 2 * x1;
  e1 = v1y - 2 * y1;
  c1 = a = 4 * (d * d + d1 * d1);
  c1 += b = 4 * (d * e + d1 * e1);
  c1 += c = e * e + e1 * e1;
  c1 = 2 * Math.sqrt(c1);
  a1 = 2 * a * (u = Math.sqrt(a));
  u1 = b / u;
  a = 4 * c * a - b * b;
  c = 2 * Math.sqrt(c);
  return (
    (a1 * c1 + u * b * (c1 - c) + a * Math.log((2 * u + u1 + c1) / (u1 + c))) /
    (4 * a1)
  );
}
```

Now, I am trying to space markers evenly. I thought that making "entropy" smooth - dividing the total length by the step length would result in the `n` markers, so going using the 1/nth step over `t` would do the trick. However, this does not work. The correlation between `t` and distance on the curve is not linear.

How do I solve the equation "backwards" - knowing the control point, the start, and the length of the curved path, calculate the end-point?

Comment: Found another solution at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6009/bezier-curve-arc-length and it seems to be the same as "my" `quadraticBezierLength()`, and it too gives a wrong result.

Comment: Given `quadraticBezierLength(100, 100,200,100.001,300,100) == 200.0000000030346` and that the result is always > than the distance between end points the function looks good. Note that the function fails if the control point is on the line between end points

Comment: Based on https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing there is not a good approximation for points at distance, at least not for the generic bezier curve case. The numerical (Newton) solution is always an option, yet a formula would have been much better.

Comment: However, it seems that the tracing example covers a cubic function case - two control points. I know that quartic is the highest-order polynomial equation that can be solved by radicals in the general case. Perhaps here too a solution for quadratic equations exists [while a generic one for higher-order curves does not], or at least a good approximation for such a solution, without having to resort to numeric solutions. ???

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what you mean by "space markers evenly" but I do have some code that I did with curves and markers that maybe can help you ...

Run the code below, it should output a canvas like this:
[image]

```js
function drawBezierCurve(p0, p1, p2, p3) {
  distance = 0
  last = null
  for (let t = 0; t <= 1; t += 0.0001) {
    const x = Math.pow(1 - t, 3) * p0[0] + 3 * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * t * p1[0] + 3 * (1 - t) * Math.pow(t, 2) * p2[0] + Math.pow(t, 3) * p3[0];
    const y = Math.pow(1 - t, 3) * p0[1] + 3 * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * t * p1[1] + 3 * (1 - t) * Math.pow(t, 2) * p2[1] + Math.pow(t, 3) * p3[1];
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    if (last) {
      distance += Math.sqrt((x - last[0]) ** 2 + (y - last[1]) ** 2)
      if (distance >= 30) {
        ctx.rect(x - 1, y - 1, 2, 2);
        distance = 0
      }
    }
    last = [x, y]
  }
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
drawBezierCurve([0, 0], [40, 300], [200, -90], [300, 150]);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=150></canvas>
```

I created the drawBezierCurve function, there I'm using a parametric equation of a bezier curve and then I use `lineTo` to draw between points, and also we get a distance between points, the points are very close so my thinking is OK to use the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the distance, and the markers are just little rectangles.

Comment: You used numeric approach for cubic curve, it seems. The distance that you are calculating is the length of a straight line between two points, not the length of the curved path.

Comment: @IgorShmukler Yes I mentioned that ... but those points are very close to each other, in my example there are hundreds of points between markers  ... while not an exact calculation it is a good approximation ... at the end we are drawing on a screen made of finite pixels

Comment: I agree, depending on the requirements, your solution might be enough. It is not terribly relevant to my use-case, though. ;)